# How to get maximum value from output of SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: `task_runs` and `integer_values`. I am running a query to get this output:

```
task_name         start_time            value
acc_clock         2010-05-27              4
icc_opy           2010-05-28              5
icc_dtaf          2010-05-29              3
acc_clock         2010-05-25             34
icc_ruty          2010-05-23             33
icc_ruty          2010-05-22             45
```

This is my output of a SQL query which is coming from two different tables. Note that in this output, `task_name` is occuring twice. But I want the output to have only one occurrence of `task_name` and its associated value should be the maximum `start_time`, like this:

```
task_name         start_time            value
icc_opy           2010-05-28              5
icc_dtaf          2010-05-29              3
acc_clock         2010-05-25             34
icc_ruty          2010-05-23             33
```

My query is:

```
select t.task_name, max(t.start_time), i.value
from task_runs t, integer_values i
where i.run_id = t.id
and t.username = 'amit'
and t.start_time > '2010-05-20'
order by t.task_name
group by t.task_name
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql 
May be its help u

Comment: @user979553 can you post the query you used to get the first result set?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT task_name, MAX(start_time) FROM your_table GROUP BY task_name;
```

Group by will take duplicates and group them in this case on task_name. And MAX will take the highest value. SO: when more tasks exist with the same name, display it once and show only the one with the highest start_time.

Comment: This actually wont necessarily show the value that is associated with the MAX(start_time)... just any value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take a look at [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) and [MAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable y
JOIN 
 (select task_name, MAX(start_time) maxtime FROM yourTable GROUP BY task_name) highest
ON y.task_name = highest.task_name AND y.start_time = highest.start_time
```

Comment: This query's performance is horrible. Can you please explain why my solution doesn't work or why you are choosing this approach?

Comment: Your query works, if he only wants task_name and start_time. But if he wants value?

Comment: I am sorry, but that will not work. The value returned will not always be the value that is in the same row as the max_time.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH max_start AS
(
SELECT 
task_name
,start_time
,value
,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY taskname ORDER BY start_time DESC) as row
FROM your_table
)
SELECT 
task_name
,start_time
,value
FROM max_start 
WHERE row = 1
```

Comment: Thnks for providin solution

Comment: @NavrattanBansal - if this answer was helpful to you, please feel free to accept it